# Linux creating new media every time

Tags: linux, automounting, uuid, media

I'm new Linux user so be kind.

Whenever I boot my Linux on PC I get different uuid from media.

See this dir: /media/my_name/2B283D3C465F37B722/folder_name/folder_namev1

And when I open for example InteliJ I open that folder manually. Thats good. Now when I turn off my PC and start it again I can not load that project until I manually again choose folder. Why? Because this 2B283D3C465F37B722 is not same anymore.

How I can stop Linux creating new uuid like that? I also have a problem now with Steam, whenever I try to launch some game I need to install it again because of that, Steam can not recognize it

I tried some cmds but dint work and I'm scared to not screw up more.

```
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│    ntfs         System Reserved
│                       50782D45782D2AE4                                    
├─sda2
│    ntfs               300C7DBC0C7D7E22                                    
├─sda3
│    vfat   FAT32       7EB4-3DE8                             500,3M     2% /boot/efi
├─sda4
│                                                                           
└─sda5
     ext4   1.0         f5ca8302-5be7-41de-a052-9d9f064d03d2  392,8G    13% /
sdb                                                                         
├─sdb1
│                                                                           
└─sdb2
     ntfs               2B283D3C465F37B7                       99,9G    57% /media/my_name/2B283D3C465F37B726
```

Comment: Well, are you talking about the same drive/partition (without having it reformatted)? (If you are, the behavior is unexpected. I have never heard such report and it's not quite possible. The only reason I could think of would be something actually keeps changing the volume ID of the filesystem.)

Comment: What do you mean by "media", is this an external USB disk? USB stick? Network mount? What's your computer?

Comment: I dont have any USB in PC while this is happening. I installed Linux Mint with dual boot using Windows on other side. Whenever I start my PC I get new 2B283D3C465F37B722 as I said. So for example if I boot PC on Linux Mint my directory is for example /media/my_name/2B283D3C465F37B722/folder_name/folder_namev1 and then turn off, boot up again and try to open that folder in some IDE for example it doesn't exist, but exist for example in /media/my_name/new_id_of_those_big_numbers/folder_name/folder_namev1

Its not formatted

Comment: So is /mnt/media/some_id mountpoint(s) of the Windows system drive ("C: drive")?

Comment: Also, does the id change if you reboot from Linux to Linux (no booting to Windows in between)?

Comment: One more thing, does the whole id change when it changes? Or does only half of it change?

Comment: Linux to Linux, Windows to Linux, it doesnt metter

This is for example now 2B283D3C465F37B724

So as far as I can see just tree last numbers

Comment: Hmm, so you have actually been seeing id of 18 digits / characters instead of 16? (I thought you were just randomly typing and typed it too long than what you had really seen.) And every time it changes, only the last 2 digits / characters changes? Can you add the output of `sudo lsblk -f` to your question?

Comment: No, no, I didnt insert any random numbers, all that big numbers was copy > paste.

Updated question with output.

Comment: I don't know what's the reason of this. Never heard of such behavior before and I wonder what's the purpose of this changing suffix and where it is even stored (it seems to be a "count"). I do have workarounds for you though. If you want to stick with automounting (udisks2, I suppose), you can set a filesystem label (either in Windows or with `ntfslabel` in Linux). IIRC udisks2 prefer fs label as the name of the mountpoint if it's set. Or you can use an fstab entry to mount it on some fixed mountpoint instead (you'll need to use the uid=/gid= mount options btw).